# is there a good thread tracer for C/C++ like Haskell's Threadscope?

Tags: c, multithreading

Is there a free and open source tool like [Threadscope](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/threadscope/) (and newer than [NPTL Trace tool](http://nptltracetool.sourceforge.net/)) to analyze CPU utilization/threading errors?

Comment: Can you specify how do you want analyze a CPU utilization (do you want to know, if all CPUs are  used or not?) and which kind of threading errors you are interested in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPU utilization analysis and threading error checker can be not in the same tool. To find threading errors, huge analysis of memory accesses is needed. I can name valngrind's helgrind http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html and google threadSanitizer, tsan (based on helgrind) http://code.google.com/p/data-race-test/wiki/ThreadSanitizer. Both tools do a run-time instrumentation of code via valgrind's libVEX dynamic code modification framework. This leads to huge slowdown, e.g. for Helgrind (from hg-manual):

> Performance can be very poor. *Slowdowns on the order of **100:1** are not unusual*. There is limited scope for performance improvements.

For CPU utilization, you should use the profiler, which does affect performance of the application only a little (up to 5-10 %), e.g. `oprofile` or linux's perf https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

If threads in your application are added by using OpenMP, there are solutions to analyze OMP thread balancing, e.g. Intel's openMP implementation can record some information like shown here [.gvs (GuideView openmp statistics) file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983818/gvs-guideview-openmp-statistics-file-format)